# FPT for Special Matching

Tags: dynamic-programming

> In Special Matching, we are given an undirected graph $G$, a function $w:E\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, and an integer $k$. The objective is to decide whether $G$ contains a matching $M$ of size at least $k$ such that for every two edges $e , e' \in M$ then $w(e) \neq w(e')$.

I want to design a random Dynamic Programing that solves Special Matching at $O^*(4^k)$ ie.
$O(4^k \bullet n^{O(1)})$.

Hint: need to color the vertices with $2k$ colors and solve the assumption that all the vertices in the solution get different colors.

Comment: Please attribute the sources of this problem.  Where did you get it?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you try to color each vertex independently with one of 2k colors, and proceed from there?  Can you find a "rainbow special matching"?  What is the probability that if there exists a special matching, it will be colorful?

Answer (score 1):

it's actually a very simple reduction to 3-set-packing.
the solution can be found here:
https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/8124/pdf/LIPIcs-MFCS-2017-71.pdf

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What is the algorithm?  Where in that paper should one look?  Can you summarize the reduction and how that leads to the quoted time bound?  Please provide a full citation for that reference.  We expect references to fulfill scholarly norms: include at least the title, authors, and where it is published, so that we can still make sense of this answer even if the link stops working, and so that others with a question about this paper can find this page by searching on its title.  Thank you!